# Collect all the values of an attribute existed in a balise into one

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file define as following :

```
  <test>
    <years year ="2001">
  </test>
  <test>
    <years year ="2002">
  </test>
  <test>
    <years year ="20013">
   </test>
```

How to get all attributes existed in a file xml , and add it into it ? Something like that :

```
<test>
  <years>2001,2002,2003</years>
  </test>
  <test>
    <years year ="2001">
  </test>
  <test>
    <years year ="2002">
  </test>
  <test>
    <years year ="2003">
   </test>
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, your xml sample is invalid. You've to add root element and close `years`

Check this out:

Input xml file:

```
<root>
  <test>
    <years year="2001" />
  </test>
  <test>
    <years year="2002" />
  </test>
  <test>
    <years year="20013" />
  </test>
</root>
```

The code:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    XElement root = XElement.Load("data.xml");
    var years = string.Join(",", root.Descendants("years").Select(x => x.Attribute("year").Value));
    root.Add(new XElement("test", new XElement("years", years)));
    root.Save("data.xml");
}
```

Result file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <test>
    <years year="2001" />
  </test>
  <test>
    <years year="2002" />
  </test>
  <test>
    <years year="20013" />
  </test>
  <test>
    <years>2001,2002,20013</years>
  </test>
</root>
```